# ASP.NET run javascript server side using C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I understand that if I am invoking a function on button click in ASP.NET I have to run the C# code on the server, by using runat=sever and call the javascript function. But doesn't this defeat the actual purpose of using javascript, which is validate data first on the client side before making a trip to the server?

Comment: Why are you validating your data using JavaScript when you can use the [Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx)?

Comment: I guess I wasn't aware of the validation controls. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to give up on either.

When you submit your form to the server, you can choose to pass it through a JavaScript function first.

Imagine you had a text box, and you want to make sure this text box contains any data before it is being processed on the server.

A very simple practice would be adding a validating function to the "onsubmit" event within the  tag:

```
<form method="post" id="my_form" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validateForm();">
```

Then just write a JavaScript function that validates your form:

```
function validateForm() {
    myTextBox = document.getElementByID("NonEmptyTextBox").value;
    if (myTextBox.length == 0) {
        //display error message
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The form will not be passed onto the server without receiving a TRUE value from the JavaScript validation function.

Comment: When javascript is disabled or fails then the form is posted anyway, so input should be checked on the server too!

Comment: I could not agree more, server side validation is often more important than client side validation (e.g. you'll never see a billing process that's validated on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

You can return true or false from javascript function to allow or disallow postback depending on validation result.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validateData();" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function validateData()
{
   //Validation code
   return boolValidationResult.            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asp.net validation controls to automatically validate on the client **and** on the server.

Validation on the client uses javascript to prevent unnecessary postbacks.
Validation on the server is to prevent invalid input on your form by clients/bots with javascript disabled (or when your javascript fails to run correctly).

I mainly use the RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator, the combination of these two can do almost anything. Sometimes a CustomValidator is needed, but then you'll have to write two validation functions, one in javascript and one for server-side validation.